# Whats the difference between "template <class T, class C>" and "template <class T> template <class C>"

Tags: c++, templates

Since I'm a fan of separating interface and implementation, instead of implementing a template class solely in the header, I separated it into a .h and .tpp (.tpp so that it's not compiled with *.cpp). I then included the tpp at the end of the header file just before the `#endif` in the header guard. Because of this choice, in the implementation (.tpp), to define a function, I would have to define each function by referring to it by its template parameters like so:

```
template <class T>
T MyTemplate<T>::functionName(T t){...}
```

However, I noticed when defining a member function with an extra template parameter, I would have to define it by referring to it using:

```
template <class T>
template <class C>
T MyTemplate<T>::extraTParamFunc(T t, C c){...}
```

instead of:

```
template <class T, class C>
T MyTemplate<T>::extraTParamFunc(T t, C c){...}   //no declaration matches 'T MyTemplate<T>::extraTParamFunc(T, C)'
```

This left me puzzled. So why is this? Whats the difference between `template <class T, class C>` and `template <class T> template <class C>`?

Also, here is an example of the .h and .tpp just in case this bears any relevance:

```
//MyTemplate.h
#ifndef MYTEMPLATE_H
#define MYTEMPLATE_H

template <class T>
class MyTemplate {

template <class C>
T extraTParamFunc(T t, C c);
...
}

#include "MyTemplate.tpp"
#endif //MYTEMPLATE_H
```

```
//MyTemplate.tpp
#include "MyTemplate.h"

template <class T>
template <class C>
T MyTemplate<T>::extraTParamFunc(T t, C c){...}

...
```

Comment: There are 2 rows of template parameters since there are 2 different templates. If you could write the parameters of nested templates on the same line, how could you or the compiler dinstinguish between the twp?

Comment: It would cause no end of confusion with using partial template specialisation.

Comment: Off topic but to be honest I think you're misunderstanding the prupose of separating interface and implementation. It's doesn't refer to physical separation (i.e. putting the code in different files) but to ensuring the users of your code are not dependent on the details of your implementation. Using a separate file for template definitions is solving a non-problem IMHO.

Comment: @john Actually there is a good reason to at least make the definitions out-of-line and that is readability. If the interface of a (templated) class is buried among the inlined implementation details it is very hard to read and understand what the class does. Of course there is no need to separate them into their own file at any rate as you say.

Comment: When you instanciate a template, the template type parameter is part of your type. So here, you're type depend on T. C is not part of the struct type but is part of the function signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the answer in principle in your header file:

```
template <class T>
class MyTemplate {

template <class C>
T extraTParamFunc(T t, C c);
...
}
```

The class `MyTemplate` is a template. Inside this template, you define another template, the function `MyTemplate::extraTParamFunc`. Also if you write the full function name with template parameters you can see this: `MyTemplate<T>::extraTParamFunc<C>()`. This is something different then `MyTemplate<T,C>::extraTParamFunc()` or `MyTemplate::extraTParamFunc<T,C>()` would be.

So you have a template inside a template, and the syntax needs to reflect this. If you make template specializations, in particular partial ones, or if you have optional template arguments, the syntax would be ambiguous if C++ would allow you to combine both templates in a single `template<>` line.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant: "This is something different then MyTemplate<T, C>::extraTParamFunc() or MyTemplate::extraTParamFunc<T, C>() would be." ??

Comment: Ah yes sorry, now I see the edit. Somehow the template arguments got lost... Thanks for the correction!